# Split text into logical blocks

Tags: python, nlp

I have an array of (insurance) contracts (in .docx format) processing of which I'm trying to automate.

Current task at hand is to split every contract into so called clauses - parts of contract which describe some specific risk or exclusion from cover.

For example, it can be just one sentence – “This contract covers loss or damage due to fire” or several paragraphs of text that give more details and explain what type of fire this contract covers and what damage is reimbursed.

Good thing is that usually contracts are formatted in some way or another. In best possible scenario, whole contract is a numbered list with items and sub items and we simply can split it by certain level of list hierarchy.

Bad thing is that this is not always the case and the list can be not numbered, but alphabetical or not list at all in word terms: each line starts with a number or a letter user typed in manually. Or it can be not letters or numbers at all, but some amount of spaces or tabs. Or clauses can be separated by their titles that are typed in ALL CAPS.

So the visual representation of structure varies from contract to contract.

So my question is what is the best approach to this task? Regexp? Some ML algo? Maybe there are open source scripts out there that were written to deal with this or similar tasks? Any help will be most welcome!

**EDIT (24.12.2019):**

Found this repo on github: https://github.com/bmmidei/SliceCast

Form its description: "This repository explores a neural network approach to segment podcasts based on topic of discussion. We model the problem as a binary classification task where each sentence is either labeled as the first sentence of a new segment or a continuation of the current segment. We embed sentences using the Universal Sentence Encoder and use an LSTM-based classification network to obtain the cutoff probabilities. Our results indicate that neural network models are indeed suitable for topical segmentation on long, conversational texts, but larger datasets are needed for a truly viable product.

Read the full report for this work here: [Neural Text Segmentation on Podcast Transcripts](https://github.com/bmmidei/SliceCast/blob/master/Neural_Text_Segmentation_on_Podcast_Transcripts.pdf)"

Answer (score 3):

The best course of action for this task is to improve the semantic information found in the document using annotations that rely on word styles. For instance:

- add block style for contracts
- add a paragraph style for title of contract
- add a paragraph style for features of the contract

You can drill down at the inline level and add inline styles that allow to extract more granual information like a keyword inline style.

Then, you can process the `.docx` file using a python library or maybe convert it to libreoffice and then process it.

That is a classic annotation task for text documents. It is much easier and less costly to setup that alternatives like having a specific (web) app to input the different features you need.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Pawpaw](https://github.com/rlayers/pawpaw) - a text segmentation framework that allows you to quickly build complex parsers for lexical data. The resulting segments are automatically organized into tree graphs that can be serialized, traversed, and searched using a powerful structured query language.